# MongoDB failed to start after adding keyFile config

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-4.0

I have issue with mongod service after adding keyFile in config.
I follow instruction from here : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-with-keyfile-access-control/

after adding keyFile in config, and restart the service, it give me this error :

```
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1
```

I already set chmod 400 to the keyfile and set permission to mongod.
Also have check and follow instruction from this https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/174014, but still no luck

anyone maybe know what is the problem that causing that error?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The reason for your error should be logged in the log file specified in the `--logpath` parameter. Please update the question with the error message details.

Answer (score 1):

As [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591101/starting-mongod-fork-error-child-process-failed-exited-with-error-number-1) `Mr. onetwopunch` said that I had the same thing and it turned out to be a permissions issue .If the owner of the child process cannot access the log path or the log path does not exist, it will fail.

What I did was put the log directory in my home directory:

```
mkdir ~/log
mongod --fork --logpath ~/log/mongodb.log
```